# How can I make table name from two string column?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to make a PL/SQL script.
The inputs are a schema name and a table name. How can I make it to a table name?

So e.g. I'd like to do this:

```
create or replace procedure proc(schema in varchar2, table in varchar2) is
begin
select * from 'schema.table';
end;

begin
proc('db', 'items');
end;
```

So I'd like to get everything from db.items.

I've tried concat, `( 'schema' || '.' || 'table')`, put it in a variable, but non of these has worked.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is dynamic sql. Example that will return and print the count of rows (you can change it accordingly to your needs):

```
SQL> set serveroutput on  -- to be able to see the printed results.
SQL> create or replace procedure proc(p_schema in varchar2, p_table in varchar2) is
    v_sql varchar2(100);
    v_result number;
begin
    v_sql := 'select count(*) from :1' || '.' || ':2';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql into v_result USING p_schema, p_table;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Total rows in table: '|| v_result );
end;
```

Comment: You should only use these kind of procedure internally and not allow users to input the variables as this could lead to security issues (SQL-Injection). If you only need the number of record you would better `SELECT NUM_ROWS FROM DBA_TABLES WHERE OWNER = p_schema AND TABLE_NAME = p_table`...